# INPUT with comma vs. semi

Tags: applesoft-basic, microsoft-basic

I certainly don't recall this at the time, but I'll ask to be sure.

According to the GW-BASIC documentation, a semicolon between the INPUT prompt and the variable [suppresses the question-mark prompt](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/input.html).

I do not believe this was the case on the Apple or PET/C64, anyone have a sim handy to try?

My interpreter is coming along, if I get another day or two free I'll post it for people to try.

Comment: Your linked document says that it's the comma that suppresses the question-mark: *A comma may be used instead of a semicolon after prompt string to suppress the question mark.*  There are also examples that are consistent with semicolon being the option with the question-mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma syntax does not work in Commodore BASIC, neither on the PET (Commodore BASIC V4.0), nor on C64 (Commodore BASIC V2.0), C16/116 (Commodore BASIC V3.5) or Commodore 128 (Commodore BASIC V7.0). Using a construction like `INPUT "ENTER SOMETHING",A$` yields a `SYNTAX ERROR`. There are however other ways to suppress the question mark prompt on a C64, see the answers to [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4883/c64-basic-how-to-suppress-the-sign-when-using-the-input-command).

Comment: " Using a construction like INPUT "ENTER SOMETHING",A$ yields a SYNTAX ERROR:" - do you mean a semi in there, or the comma? This example is the opposite of your opening statement.

Comment: The comma syntax does not work in Commodore BASIC - thanks for the correction. `INPUT "ENTER SOMETHING";A$` (with a semicolon) would be a valid statement when used in a program line.

Answer (score 0):

> INPUT with comma vs. semi

I'm not sure what this is supposed to ask, but ...

> According to the GW-BASIC documentation, a semicolon between the INPUT prompt and the variable suppresses the question-mark prompt.
>
> I do not believe this was the case on the Apple or PET/C64,

It was on the Apple and all other MS-BASIC versions, but not on the PET.

Examples:

```
10 INPUT A
20 INPUT "NUMBER"; A
10 INPUT ""; A
```

will display on an Apple II ("`_` "being the cursor)

```
?_
NUMBER_
_
```

while the PET does always give the question mark *and* a space

```
? _
NUMBER? _
? _
```

---

In addition maybe relevant here that the [ECMA-55 (1978)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-55,%201st%20Edition,%20January%201978.pdf) standard "For minimal BASIC" (adopted by ANSI as ANSI X3.60-1978) makes the whole prompt implementation defined and optional, while recommending:

```
   It is recommended that the input-prompt consists of a question-
   mark followed by a single space.
```

So Commodore's implementation is close to standard .. albeit I'm not sure if by purpose.

*[Also, if you're about to write any new BASIC, make sure it is able to handle ECMA-55 programs as means for general compatibility. The National Bureau of Standards' [Minimal BASIC Test Suite](https://archive.org/search.php?query=nbs%20minimal%20basic) might be of help]*

Later ECMA-116 defines that

```
  If an input-prompt specifier is present in the input-statement, then
  the implementation-defined input-promt shall not be output;
```

Though, it also requests a quite different syntax using keywords and a colon to seperate between modifiers and variable list:

```
INPUT PROMT "Name? ": A$
```

While using a keyword does allow for a prompt to be supplied in a string variable, the colon may tick off many. ECMA-116 is eventually a great language definition, but came way to late for any influence.

---

Input in (early) MS BASIC has another nice side effect when using the notation without assigning a prompt. A statement like

```
INPUT ;A
```

which should produce a syntax error right away when executed, will still *first* prompt for a value, only to break *after* it has been entered.

Comment: Not just the PET, but also VIC-20, C64 and even BASIC 7.0 on the C-128.